# Android file chooser

Tags: android, file-upload, file-io, filechooser, android-afilechooser

I want to make a file uploader. And I hence I need a file chooser but I don't want to write this by myself. I find OI file manager and I think it suits me.
But how can I force user to install OI file manager?
If I cannot , is there a better way to include a file manager in my app?
Thx

Comment: I use https://github.com/18446744073709551615/android-file-chooser-dialog

Comment: https://github.com/criss721/Android-FileSelector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104787/3141844 + https://github.com/criss721/Android-FileSelector

Answer (score 273, accepted):

**EDIT** (*02 Jan 2012*):

I created a small open source Android Library Project that streamlines this process, while also providing a **built-in file explorer** (in case the user does not have one present). It's extremely simple to use, requiring only a few lines of code.

You can find it at GitHub: [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).

---

**ORIGINAL**

If you want the user to be able to choose any file in the system, you will need to include your own file manager, or advise the user to download one. I believe the best you can do is look for "openable" content in an `Intent.createChooser()` like this:

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You would then listen for the selected file's `Uri` in `onActivityResult()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file 
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
            // Get the path
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
            Log.d(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
            // Get the file instance
            // File file = new File(path);
            // Initiate the upload
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The `getPath()` method in my `FileUtils.java` is:

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    }
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'd even go so far as to also direct them to app on the market.

Comment: Ｔhx, but Ｉ get the content uri ---content://org.openintents.cmfilemanager/mimetype//mnt/sdcard/1318638826728.jpg
instead of file path.
Could I convert it into file path?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to get the file path, as well as creating a File instance that gives you convenience callbacks like file.getName() and file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: But I can't find FileUtils....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my FileUtils.getPath() at first.

Comment: without use file explorer it`s possible?can we make to display file structure in android?

Comment: On Google Code the license was explicitly Apache 2.0, is it still the case on GitHub? Thanks.

Comment: @Bicou Thanks for the note. Your nudge helped me to stop being lazy and make some minor changes. :-) I just pushed an update to the library that includes the license.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils . What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the `getPath()` code!  I found on one device for me `cursor.getString(column_index)` returns a `file:///` URL, and I had to run it through a second pass to extract the actual path name.

Comment: @Bear You just need to copy that getPath method to your own class and that's it!

Comment: Do I have to use intents even if I don't need 3rd party components? Can this be used like a DialogFragment?

Comment: @DavidDoria Sure, you can also simply call `startActivity(Context, FileChooserActivity.class)` and set the theme you want in the Manifest. Listen for the `Uri` in `onActivityResult` just as you would normally.

Comment: @PaulBurke Sorry, I'm very new to this. I don't see a startActivity function here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29 that takes anything but an intent? The closest I found online was startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileChooserActivity.class)); - is that the best way?

Comment: @DavidDoria My apologies! I did mean `startActivity(Intent)`.

Comment: how can I enable multi select ..?

Comment: @PaulBurke: I am using your method to attach a file and upload it to server. But I am facing an error, can you please help me. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882833/file-not-found-exception-when-trying-to-upload-file-to-xampp-server-from-android/30883016?noredirect=1#comment49807367_30883016. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer does not consider the uri like this:"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:62".

Comment: @wangqi060934: how did you manage to work with such uri? please share your experience to achieve the functionality

Comment: @MehulJoisar,the library " aFileChooser" is perfect now.

Comment: Or you can use this one: https://www.github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker

Comment: Sir, how to filter a specific file type like pdf, doc ect...

Comment: Here you can find all cases to select file from document and all types of mobiles                                              https://github.com/memo1231014/MUT-master/blob/master/MUT/src/com/example/androidprogramminghelper/FileOperations.java

Comment: @PaulBurke - Thank you very much i used you android studio project and it worked great. The only problem i had is that when the `onActivityResult` function was called the `REQUEST_CHOOSER` did not trigger the correct action - found in your git-hub project, in your _README.markdown_ file  under _usage_  in your `switch`. (i changed it to `REQUEST_CODE`)

Comment: is this lib provide multiple file selection ?

Comment: Here path getiing null some time,i can see in log "coloumn name _data not able to find" message.

Comment: Today, there are a lot of deprecated classes/methods in the module like 'AsyncTaskLoader'. Needs some updates.

Comment: Hi i have an issue in onActivityResult  when i didn't select any file and press back it doesn't open again can any one help ?

Answer (score -2):

I used AndExplorer for this purpose and my solution is popup a dialog and then redirect on the market to install the misssing application:

My startCreation is trying to call external file/directory picker. If it is missing call show installResultMessage function.

```
private void startCreation(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard"));

    intent.setDataAndType(startDir,
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");
    intent.putExtra("browser_filter_extension_whitelist", "*.csv");
    intent.putExtra("explorer_title", getText(R.string.andex_file_selection_title));
    intent.putExtra("browser_title_background_color",
            getText(R.string.browser_title_background_color));
    intent.putExtra("browser_title_foreground_color",
            getText(R.string.browser_title_foreground_color));
    intent.putExtra("browser_list_background_color",
            getText(R.string.browser_list_background_color));
    intent.putExtra("browser_list_fontscale", "120%");
    intent.putExtra("browser_list_layout", "2");

    try{
         ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager()
                                 .getApplicationInfo("lysesoft.andexplorer", 0 );

            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        showInstallResultMessage(R.string.error_install_andexplorer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This methos is just pick up a dialog and if user wants install the external application from market

```
private void showInstallResultMessage(int msg_id) {
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    dialog.setMessage(getText(msg_id));
    dialog.setButton(getText(R.string.button_ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.setButton2(getText(R.string.button_install),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=lysesoft.andexplorer"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: So, one of the requirements for your app users is... install AndExplorer?!