# Automatically open Intent Chooser for the file Android

Tags: android, file, android-intent, mime-types

I want to open a file in `android`. What i want to do is if the file is of type `Image` then i want to open `Intent Chooser` which contains applications that can view the image, and if it is of video type, then open Intent Chooser with applications that can view videos. How can i  achieve this?

Comment: go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found a solution. I am pasting it here so it may help other users.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(path);

    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i need your help.Can you please help me?

Comment: Before `context.startActivity(intent);`, you should add these lines (to show `Toast` if no app found to open the file: `PackageManager manager = mActivity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  if(info.isEmpty())
   Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No app found to open this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  else
   context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") rather than just indexOf ?

Comment: i am in a ClickListener how i get the context? In order to call context.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

You should decide and know whether the file is video or image. You may do it by looking at the extension of the files.

After that you can open videos like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(result), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

and images like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(result), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

`Android` system will open the `Intent Chooser` automatically.

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. I don't want to open only image or video. I want that whatever file i pass, intent chooser lists appropriate application for that file.

Comment: Ok then you just need to change the type parameter accordingly. If it is text "text/*" it should be. You cannot do it automatically I guess. In most of the file explorers they categorize them into text, images, videos and open them accordingly. For all the files that not fit a category, they ask user what kind of a file this.

Comment: I have found a solution. See my answer. Thanks :)