# Android: Download File then show app chooser to open it in?

Tags: android, android-intent

So I've been looking all around and can't seem to figure it out, or maybe because I'm inside the emulator?

Basically I'm trying to download a file, and then show a app chooser so the user can freely choose which ever app to open it in.

One thing I'm not sure about is, how do you do a wild card mime type for the intent? I mean for example the downloaded file could be shared and opened by the mail client as an attachment, so really it should support anything.

For the purpose of brevity, the download code works and downloads, so assume the download is completed and the file is in the cache directory:

```
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// Create intent to show chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(install, "Open in...");

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (install.resolveActivity(_progressDialog.getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    _progressDialog.getContext().startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: If you open a file, shouldn't it show what program to open in? All you have to do is open the file.

Comment: No...? You still need to be explicit with the intent, as far as I've read, I could be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically open Intent Chooser for the file Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148966/automatically-open-intent-chooser-for-the-file-android)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide the mime type as well e.g. with

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri, mimetype);
```

where mimetype is like "text/plain". You can extract it from file extension, header using special method or lookup table (I don't recall how exactly it is done now).

But that's not working either at least in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below intent to attach thefile & send email

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(root, xmlFilename);
if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Attachment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
    return;
}
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
```