# How to call open with dialog for an Android app

Tags: android, file, open-with

I have an Android app for example a file manager.

When the user clicks a file I want to call open with dialog and run the app to open the file.

How can I do that?

Comment: take look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148966/automatically-open-intent-chooser-for-the-file-android

Comment: i have this code:                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File file = new File(dirPath);

                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1);
                    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                    
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
but it crashes.

Comment: i am in a ClickListener how i get the context?

Comment: i found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed