# File picking browser showing empty directories

Tags: android, android-intent, file-browser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(requestCode){
      case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
       if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
    textFile.setText(FilePath);
       }
       break;

      }
     }
    }
```

But it is showing only empty directories and not files inside them. I have astro installed on phone

Comment: refer [this ][1] answer also check if you have required permissions 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android#

Comment: No it does not show only directories which are empty. It shows all directories. But no files. You could have started to tell which picker you use as i know of at least one who behaves that way.

Comment: i am using astro and yes u r right it is showing all directories but no files. That's what i meant . My bad if i was not clear. P.S how to view files inside directories then?

Answer (score 0):

do you have required permission in your app to read external files??

you may refer this answer as well refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android#)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  I am using this . Is it okay ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it working by usin ( * / * ) instead of (files/*) but now i have problem playing them. Solutions are welcome