# Can android intent be used to access phone directory?

Tags: android, android-intent, directory

I am making an android app to open a file and send it back to a remote server. I know how to do this with a file hardcoded into the app but I want to make it so that it can search the phone's directory, choose a file then send it. I am wondering can this be done with an intent? Or is there any other approach that could be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with an Intent. You would use startActivityForResult() and specify an Intent that can launch a file picker. Now the actual Intent you use depends on which application(s) you expect will actually service this Intent for you. For example, ES File Explorer exports a custom [PICK_FILE](http://www.estrongs.com/res/develop_en.htm) action that you can use to support a file picker. With any scenario where you rely on a third party application to provide a service, you'll want some sort of fallback in case no application can handle the Intent (such as linking to an app that implements the Intent in the Google Play store). A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android) may provide some additional Intents to try for a variety of different file choosers available.