# Android - pick file

Tags: android

I'm trying to pick file with this extension : *doc* & *pdf*

I've already used this to pick Image and Video:

```
public void pickImage()
{
    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void pickVideo()
{
    Intent pickVideoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(pickVideoIntent, PICK_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I want something like that for files. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android) and use it in my code

```
public void pickFile()
{
    Intent pickFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickFileIntent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(pickFileIntent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
}
```

Actually it gives me an error in last line:        `startActivityForResult(pickFileIntent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);`

> error: cannot find symbol

How to fix it?

Comment: have you defined "int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 4711;"

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the variable "PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE" and others right?