# Is there any Intent to pick a file for all devices in android?

Tags: android

I am using following intent to select any file from my device but its only selecting file for Samsung Tablet not for any other device.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8946030/3162918

Comment: yes i have tried this but did not work for me.

Comment: it should be that, according to the documentation. Maybe you are doing something wrong? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you should use an [`ACTION_PICK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) intent with the [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method:

```java
final int ACTION_PICK_RESULT = 0;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_PICK_RESULT);
```

You can then retrieve the file in the `onActivityResult()` method of your activity.

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData();
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver()
                    .openFileDescriptor(returnUri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();

            // TODO Do stuff with the file
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

See this page for more information: [Requesting a Shared File](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html)