# Directory not found exception after picking a file in file explorer

Tags: android, file, xamarin.android, filepath, filepicker

**EDIT:** I did some research and important for my question is this:

I use Intent object to get file path from user. He uses some random file explorer. The one I installed to emulator returns path like this:

> fileName = "file:///mnt/sdcard/Alien/PlayersBase.btb"

This doesn't work.

If I was accessing the same file programatically, knowing where file is, I would do it this way:

```
string str = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), "Alien/PlayersBase.btb");
```

Now

> str = "/mnt/sdcard/Alien/PlayersBase.btb"

The second path is different and works perfectly.

**So my question should be probably more like this: What can I expect to be returned by the Intent object and why string returned by the first file explorer I found on google returns something that doesn't work?**

---

*First version of question*

My target is to allow user to select a file in android and I want to copy this file to local folder of my application.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android) I took the third answer to allow user to select file on both Samsung and non Samsung devices. **The code below seems to work fine**, android gives me choice which explorer do I want to use, I can browse and select file. Just to be complete I post the code here:

```
Activity mainActivity = context as Activity;
string minmeType="*/*";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.SetType(minmeType);
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);

//special intent for Samsung file manager
Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
// if you want any file type, you can skip next line 
sIntent.PutExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", minmeType);
sIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);

Intent chooserIntent;
if (mainActivity.PackageManager.ResolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null)
{
    // it is device with samsung file manager
    chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(sIntent, "Open file");
    chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, new Intent[] { intent });
}
else
{
    chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Open file");
}
try
{
    mainActivity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 3);
}
catch
{
    SendMessageToUser("No suitable File Manager was found.");
}
```

Then I put this code to my activity

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==3 && resultCode == Result.Ok) //pick file
        OnFileSelected(data.DataString);
}
```

And I try to work with the file here

```
public void OnFileSelected(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        Stream streamSource = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string message = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Initializing streamSource however throws an exception:

> fileName = "file:///mnt/sdcard/Alien/PlayersBase.btb"

and exception is

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/file:///mnt/sdcard/Alien/PlayersBase.btb" ................."

I would understand if I didn't have rights for some folders but why does it say the folder **doesn't exist** when it is the exact file I selected in file explorer?

Comment: Your path `/file:///mnt/sdcard/Alien/PlayersBase.btb" .................` starts with `/`, it might be the reason of the error. Try to remove the first symbol

Comment: The '/' is written only in the exception string, the fileName variable is as mentioned on the end of my post, just "file:///...".

Comment: I just updated the post. The problem is in file system on android I don't know much about yet. There are extra symbols returned by file explorer "file://" that shouldn't be there. Would be nice if somebody could point me on right path as google isn't the best at finding "///" string.