# To add the attachment to email

Tags: android, email, android-sdcard, email-attachments, filechooser

I am trying to send the mail with attachment and I have writeen code for that which is working fine, but here I have written the file name which i want to attach in the program,I dont want like this I want it to be choose by the user from the sdcard.How to do it.

```
    public class DemoVoiceActivity extends Activity {
        EditText txtTo,mSubject,mMessageBody,attachment;
        String strSubject,strMessageBody;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            txtTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.to);

        mSubject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
        mMessageBody = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_content);
        attachment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.attachment);

        String[] strTo = {txtTo.getText().toString()};

        strSubject = mSubject.getText().toString();
        strMessageBody = mMessageBody.getText().toString();
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        objIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, strTo);

        objIntent.setType("plain/text"); objIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, strSubject);
        objIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MESSAGE"); objIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/q.mp4"));
        startActivity(objIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857102/975959

He provied a simple file chooser open source library.
You can then in the `onFileSelect()` method, get the file path and add it to your `objIntent`.

He also provides way of implementing it yourself, if you wish to do so.