# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Native File Explorer app: "My Files" package name

Tags: android, android-intent, package, galaxy-tab

I am trying to make a button that when on click will change the view and open up the native file explorer on a tablet. I found a potential solution with code like this:

```
fileBrowseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.My Files.android"));
        }
    });
```

The only issue I seem to have is I can't identify the name of the package that is the file explorer, I tried looking around in the app manager. I know on my Motorola phone its:

```
com.motorola.filemanager
```

Anyone know what the package name?

The possible workaround is downloading something like Astro and using that instead, but I would prefer the native app first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some apk digging and found the package name for my device...

Now I know this will not work on other devices, I tested it on Motorola device and got an error (which was expected).

The package name for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 native file browser turned out to work with the name:

**"com.sec.android.app.myfiles"**

Thanks

Comment: This works for me on a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have a native File Manager, though most OEMs usually install one of their own, or one of a developer with whom they have an agreement.

You should either use an Intent to pick the file, and maybe even provide a small file manager yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857102/1069068) answer here should help with that.

Comment: I realize that Android doesn't include a native File Manager but there is a "My Files" app that came with the the tablet that I am trying to figure out the name of the package to redirect to it.