# How to get the url of the website to which I upload a file?

Tags: android

Hi and thanks for any suggestion,

I have done my homework and tried to find an answer on SO and around, but so far I have been unable to find a solution.

I am trying to build some kind of FileManager to allow user to upload files on websites (any website, for example add an attachment to a mail in yahoo mail...)

Therefore my application registers a filter so that when the browser requests a file to upload the app opens up and provide the file to the requester (the web browser).

My question is: 
**is there a way for me to retrieve the url of the website to which the file is uploaded ?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - do you mean, you need to find what the URL is for the site you're uploading to? I would imagine just having a stored list would work easiest.

Comment: @Mike yes I need the URL for the site I ma uploading to. Bu I do dot know those URL in advance, so I must grab them somewhat when the application hands the file to the browser

Comment: There must be any information passed to your. Program to be able to 'route' the file, e.g. to Yahoo mail. What information do you get from the user?

Comment: There is no consistent and reliable way of doing so. I say consistent and reliable because there might be some app that sends some extra in the intent that might give you a reference to this url/info. However, it is not the case in general. Your job as a File Manager (your Filter) is strictly to allow the user to pick a File and return this file in the result to the calling application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question currently. my answer is relevant with the **assumption:** you want to have a direct download url to the file that been uploaded, and you wish to use this url in some point in the future to download that file...

I am afraid there is really no way getting such information.

there are many obstacles in the way of getting url to the file that been uploaded:

- there is no any system broadcast / event that been sent in this scansion
- even if the upload process was managed and initiated from you own application with you own    `WebView` - the website you uploading to not necessarily provide you information of what is the url of the uploaded file.   I know for sure that companies like yahoo not provide you this url.
- if that's not enough - **there is no necessarily such url at all!**
  the fact is that the server you uploading to is not necasserly doing anything with the uploaded file, or just not exposing him to public access with url.

from the reasons I mentioned,  developing app as you which can be done only with servers providing their own API for upload files, and returns you the url as respond.
of-course each server has it own API (if at all)  and you should speak with each one of the servers you'd like to support with it own language.  sort of mission impossible if you want to support most of the big sites...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem as to how can I get the URL where my file is uploaded. The answer is simple and lies in your Android code.

For uploading a file to some place, you need to know URL of the server/website.

So lets say you are uploading a file to

```
 www.yoursite.com/appdatafolder/
```

For uploading to the file to the given address, you have to have a `php script file sitting there`, which will communicate with your android code for uploading the data.

Lets consider the address is:

```
 www.yoursite.com/appdatafolder/upload.php
```

Now it depends on your code on how did you wrote your php script, in my case, I also send the name of the file to `upload.php` file, you can ignore it if you want or your script follows some other algo.

Lets say you want to upload `importantfile.txt`, so the url **for uploading the file** becomes

```
 www.yoursite.com/appdatafolder/upload.php?filename="importantfile.txt"
```

The address you need to provide to the user in order `to download the file` becomes:

```
 www.yoursite.com/appdatafolder/importantfile.txt
```

Now what you can do is **save this address in a local database on your phone** and use it whenever the user wants to download the file.

If you are afraid of securing the files which can be accessed/downloaded

```
 www.yoursite.com/appdatafolder/
```

you can use **htaccess**. There are alot of other security mechanisms out there for securing data on the server from hacking. htaccess is simplest example.

So this is the easiest and hassel free way of solving your problem.

If you want, I can provide the php script I used.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If their is no secure layer on the web site, data sniffing by the app could be a kind of solution. you'll also probably need to deal with content encoding like gzip.

You'll need to filter the result's. It is easy to do: You just need to look at the [application level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).
Then you can apply a second filter if you know the ip address or the hostname of the concerned site.

There is even one more filter if you know the [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). But most it is get or post most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this question: [Android file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser)? It has great example code as well as a link to a GitHub project ([aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)).