# Get a picture from filedialog in android and show it in imageview

Tags: java, android

I want to take a picture from file chooser and show it on an image view.. but when I run my app it would be stopped and doesn't work. where is problem?
this codes are code of 'MainActivity.java'.I didn't change any thing in other files of my project.MY codes are based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser) .My codes are:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
    private static final String TAG = null;
    public TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();

            }
        });
    }


    private void showFileChooser() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
        intent.setType("*/*"); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                iv.setImageURI(uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
               }
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

log is:

```
12-12 04:21:32.343: D/AndroidRuntime(1068): Shutting down VM
12-12 04:21:32.343: W/dalvikvm(1068): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a60b90)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): Process: com.example.a55j, PID: 1068
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a55j/com.example.a55j.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.example.a55j.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
12-12 04:21:32.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     ... 11 more
12-12 04:21:34.823: I/Process(1068): Sending signal. PID: 1068 SIG: 9
```

activiyt_main xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/open" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your logs here

Comment: In your main activity which one is 23 line?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh.. what? where?

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml.

Comment: maybe name of your imageview or textview wrong.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I edit to add xml file

Comment: You are setting content view after. but that textview and imageview inside in that content view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
        private static final String TAG = null;
        public TextView tv;
        public ImageView iv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showFileChooser();

                }
            });
        }


        private void showFileChooser() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
            intent.setType("*/*"); 
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            try {
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                        FILE_SELECT_CODE);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    iv.setImageURI(uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                   }
                break;
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I do it , but my problem didn't solved. when I run it my app stopped and didn't work

Comment: OK once try what Techfist Said.

Comment: Check name of the button in xml.

Comment: OK worked. but when choose a picture from file explorer imageview didn't show any thing

Comment: see this link https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooserExample/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooserexample/FileChooserExampleActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

See this   `at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)`, it means your XML file `R.layout.activity_main` does not have a button with name `button1`, check that.

```
public TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Put it inside OnCreate after setting content view, you are trying to access them even before your layout is actually inflated, thats y this error is coming.

Comment: I put `button1` myself in `activity_main.xml` and checked it. I view this button on it!!!!

Comment: I added xml file to my answer

Comment: Modifeid my answer, change your code as suggested and you will get your answer

Comment: thanks alot... solved. but when I choose a picture , imageview didn't show any thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's working on my machine.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
```

// private static final String TAG = null;

```
TextView tv;
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFileChooser();

        }
    });
}


private void showFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file 
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            iv.setImageURI(uri);
       //     Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
           }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to your `LogCat error` you are getting `NullPointerException`

Initilize your `ImageView` and `TextView` globally (before `OnCreate`) like

```
ImageView iv;
TextView tv;
```

and put `findViewById(R.id.imageView1)` and `findViewById(R.id.textView1)` within `onCreate` method.