# How to pick a file from gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to pick a file (other than image, video or audio), like pdf, ppt, docx, txt etc.,,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),Constant.SELECT_FILE);
```

Above method is not working.

When I do the action Dialog box appears With message "No Application can perform this action"

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: When I do the action Dialog box appears With message "No Application can perform this action"

Comment: This question is already answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **there is no any application** installed on device which is handle your intent with action `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. So if your device running on Android 4.4 then try with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or Implement your own File Browser Activity.

Look at https://github.com/vaal12/AndroidFileBrowser and [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The problem is that there is no app installed to handle opening the PDF. You should use the Intent Chooser, like so:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```