# How open choose directory dialog on Android java?

Tags: android

My app downloads files from the internet and I need the user to select where to save them. How to make a choice directory on the Android Java? Please give example code

Comment: Use Google. There are quite some solutions on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override `onCreateDialog` in an activity like this:

```
//In an Activity
private String[] mFileList;
private File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//yourdir//");
private String mChosenFile;
private static final String FTYPE = ".txt";    
private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;

private void loadFileList() {
    try {
        mPath.mkdirs();
    }
    catch(SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to write on the sd card " + e.toString());
    }
    if(mPath.exists()) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                return filename.contains(FTYPE) || sel.isDirectory();
            }

        };
        mFileList = mPath.list(filter);
    }
    else {
        mFileList= new String[0];
    }
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

    switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
            builder.setTitle("Choose your file");
            if(mFileList == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Showing file picker before loading the file list");
                dialog = builder.create();
                return dialog;
            }
            builder.setItems(mFileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mChosenFile = mFileList[which];
                    //you can do stuff with the file here too
                }
            });
            break;
    }
    dialog = builder.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

small open source Android Library Project that streamlines this process, while also providing a built-in file explorer (in case the user does not have one present). It's extremely simple to use, requiring only a few lines of code.

You can find it at GitHub: https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

For More Details:

[Android file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser)