# Get the Path from a File inside file directory in Android

Tags: android, file, path

I have a file named `abikor.txt` inside the `files` directory in the private app folder:

`/data/data/myapp/files/abikor.txt`

How can I get the path of this file?

I have seen the following questions but they don't address my problem.

- [Get the directory from a file path in java (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594297/get-the-directory-from-a-file-path-in-java-android)
- [get the path of file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099813/get-the-path-of-file-in-android)

(In general, how to get the path of a file stored under `/files` directory in the private app directory?)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the Internal Storage path you need to specify some thing like this

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then create a file object from the path

```
File file = new File(path + "/abikor.txt");
```

and if you want to **Read the file from it** then

```
int length = (int) file.length();

byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    in.read(bytes);
} finally {
    in.close();
}

String contents = new String(bytes);
```