# Android - Pick file from mobile and send file to php server

Tags: android, file, file-upload

I am new in android developement. I have to pick a file (doc, pdf or xls), and send it to php server. I had successfully done the same it with image. Now please guide me how I able to upload file from device to php server. Suggest any link, example or tutorial.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: refer https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/android-http-client.html

Comment: I refer this, but file send to server is empty file. File having no content.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this 
First make StartActivityForResult

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And then onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file 
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
            // Get the path
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
            Log.d(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
            // Get the file instance
            // File file = new File(path);
            // Initiate the upload
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and this is the getPath method

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    }
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and this is the link for original answer [File Chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser)