# How to upload a file and read the contents of a file in android

Tags: android, file, file-upload

I am working on an android application where I want users to upload a file and I want to read the contents of uploaded file and display it . I have been reading files from SD card but I now I need the user to upload a file . I searched a lot but I didn't get any solution for it.

My code for reading the file from SD card

```
   File file = new File(dir, "/tounzip/b.txt");
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

Its reading the file contents successfully but Is there any way to make the user upload the file and read the contents from it ? Any help would be great !! Thanks !!

Comment: What do you mean by upload a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser)

You require a file picker/file chooser.

Logic is you read the stream and save the stream in your app sandbox (app's memory i.e. /data/package..) then do whatever you want from there.

If file size is small then even a in-memory implementation will help.