# In OnactivityResult method how to convert file to ByteArray

Tags: android, arrays

Hi Guys i am quite new in android.I am trying to convert file to byte array but it throw file not found error in this line

```
       fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
```

Got stuck hear can any one have any idea
This is My Intent Chooser

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

this is my onactivityresultcode.

```
      Uri uri = data.getData();
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      FileInputStream fis;
      try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int n;
      while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
      baos.write(buf, 0, n);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      byte[] bbytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I had also write code for display name.

```
    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = 
      ChatActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, 
    null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            displayName = 

    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Log.d("displayname",displayName);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    displayName = myFile.getName();
                    Log.d("filename",displayName);
                }
```

Comment: Try to log your uri.getPath() and check that file exist or not.

Comment: @R.R.M this is my getpath value   /document/image:328495

Comment: So do this file exist in your phone?

Comment: no in document there is no image

Comment: can you help me with some working code badly need it .

Comment: So how will you be able to convert an image to ByteArray that do not exist? Try to convert image that exist.

Comment: Ok. Post your whole activity code here.

Comment: ok i am editing my quetion

Comment: @R.R.M please have a look on my edited question

Comment: Try to print uri.toString() please. I want to know its output.

Comment: /document/image:328495   this is log print

Comment: And the actual path of image whch i select is  storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170804_081406

Comment: Have you reffered this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser?

Comment: hey R.R.M thanks for your help finally i got my solution hear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content

Comment: Oh... That's great... !