# How to implement folder-picker android?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, dropdownlistfor

I'm writing a small corporate program that sends photos to the company's server.

Each photo should fall into a specially allocated folder, for example photo of the forest should be in the folder nature -> forest.
The directory tree I'm getting from the server as a list of objects with fields:

- name
- id
- parentId
- prefix

Where prefix is ​​a numeric value, for example:

1. Nature - 1000;

   - Forest - 1100
   - Hill - 1200
2. Animals - 2000

   - Bear - 2100
   - Mouse - 2200
   - and so on.

In order to send a photo user needs to select the appropriate folder.
The question is, how to implement easy and clear folder-picker?

At the moment, the picker is made using AutoCompleteTextView, but in order to enter the first three letters of the folder name - this name should be remembered to the user and if the folders are around 10, then it will not be difficult, but if the folders become more than 100 - then hold all the names in the head become simply impossible.

Maybe someone have an idea how to implement the user interface to select a folder, without forcing employees to learn a hundred names?

Comment: Put all in a ListView. Or yet better ExpandableListView.

Comment: You can do it many way.... I think you can keep the directory information in sqlite and use as folder picker.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser) might be of help to you. Please use search in the future.

Comment: @greenapps, as i know ExpandableListView can have only 3 levels, in my case it's not enough

Comment: ???? You need only two levels you said.

Comment: @greenapps, you're right. Perhaps I gave an unfortunate example.