# How to add Internal and External storage to File Chooser in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, filechooser, android-afilechooser

My sample app is open file chooser and select file / directory then getting the path into EditText, I tried the methods in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser) and I reached to this result

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button browse;
    private EditText editTextPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
        editTextPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file or dir"), 1);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String Fpath = data.getDataString();
            editTextPath.setText(Fpath);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: AndroidFileChooser]

I want to add internal and external storage like this to file chooser

[image: AndroidFileChooser2]

Comment: This is the Lolipop dialog, and now changed to a newer version and Google Drive also supported. https://metactrl.com/docs/sdcard-on-lollipop/

Comment: @matio thank you It has now appeared, not I want to get full path in Edit Text because this code not getting logical path see this image https://i.imgur.com/PkakUbn.png

Comment: If this is your answer accept it as "This comment adds something useful " along the comment. Then create another thread with what you want and I'l be help there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user can tap the "..." affordance in the action bar and choose "Show internal storage" to display those options.

There is no official support for anything on `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to show internal storage options automatically, though hopefully this will be supported someday.

Comment: but I see this options in some apps appearing internal and external "SD card like this<br/><img src=""https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag5pR.png>

Comment: @MML: Presumably, [they are not playing by the rules](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72053350).

Comment: Why not add that to your answer, it's far more useful than just "There is no official support for (it)"

Comment: @TimRae: Because until it is officially supported (and hopefully becomes part of the CTS), it is unreliable.

Comment: Say, how do I offer my own content to be available for the user on this UI of the file picker (on the navigation drawer on the left) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You would need to implement [a `DocumentsProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Is there a tiny sample for this somewhere?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I doubt it can be all that tiny, given that it's a verbose API. But, there is https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a. And there is [Vault](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.0.0_r2/samples/Vault/src/com/example/android/vault/VaultProvider.java), though you might see if there is a newer version than that one.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't mind that it even shares content within the app. I learn better by samples, and the smaller the sample, the easier it is for me to go further. Sadly almost all of Google's samples tend to be the complete opposite of simple. Anyway thanks. Please if you find anything, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);`
insted `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );`