# How to pass a file from a file picker to a function?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that opens up a file picker and it outputs the path of that file in a Toast Message.
But I would like to change it such that the file that I pick is passed as a parameter to a function.

My activity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picker);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 7:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Files path is: "+ PathHolder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And it does what it is supposed to do but instead of outputting the file path, I would like to call the function

```
 importToFile()
```

From the manage class.

I would like to do something like this:

```
manage.importToFile(File1)
```

Where File1 is the file I selected from the file picker.

How can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File) class in android to work with files. Create an instance of `File` using the path of the selected file and pass it to that method of yours. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 7:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // as @Taseer Ahmad said its not a good way to get path of the file.
                //String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
                String PathHolder = getPath(this, data.getData());
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PathHolder)) {
                    File file = new File(PathHolder);
                    manager.importToFile(file);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Files path is: "+ PathHolder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
As @Taseer Ahmad said, `data.getData().getPath()` is not a safe way to get path of the selected file. This code is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857102/2940733).

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `getPath()` will fail if the `Uri` is a `content://` type or non-Uri type.  A better approach would be to use create a 'generic' file, gets its URI from `FileProvider.getUriFromFile()`, open I/O streams and then start the copy function. `InputStream` will contain the `Uri` fetched from file picker.